# Gaining access to cdn functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jwplayer

Im trying to add JWPlayer to my React component, i know in a static/server rendered webpage you can simply add the `script` tag, and then you can use the component but in react its a different story.

for example in a server rendered language like php rendering a JWPlayer component looks as follows:

```
    <script src="location of jwplayer library cdn"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myElement"></div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({ 
        "playlist": [{
           "file": "<?php echo $videourl; ?>"
            }]
        });
    </script>
```

this is easy, and there is ample documentation on how to make this work. but i want to be able to use the CDN from JWPlayer in react as well, and the most popular react package has been deprecated, and is no longer being supported. I feel like i should be able to add to the DOM the cdn, and then be able to use that to be able to finish the rest of this.

for example i have:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const JWPlayerScript = async () => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "location of jwplayer library cdn";
      script.async = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    JWPlayerScript()},[])
```

This works, however i still dont have access to any of the javascript in the cdn, my console just keeps stating that `jwplayer()` has not been defined, and its correct. it hasnt but i dont know how to extract that from the cdn to gain access to those javascript functions.

Comment: so, there's nowhere in react to add a static `<script>` tag, at all?

Comment: not necessarily, no. because react works on the Virtual DOM and not the actual DOM object itself. however you can append to the DOM in the same manner as im doing above. the problem is, even doing that, it doesnt give you access to the javascript that comes from cdn itself. thats what im trying to figure out, so i can use JWPlayer in a react application.

Comment: I do not fully know the scope of your implementation, but is it possible for you to include the JWPlayer script on the index.html page and then you can access the jwplayer object through window.jwplayer inside a react component.
Later you can add a ref to one of your component that is supposed to display the JWplayer and you can initialize the whole thing like this: window.jwplayer(myCompRef.current) .setup({ /*some code here*/ }) inside a useEffect or componentDidMount of the parent component